# Cloud sql proxy : php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for /cloudsql/**** failed

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

Hi I am trying to make a php artisan migrate with my script with a cloud sql proxy connection.
The sql proxy connection working fine but when it launch my command it fail with the error

```
---------- CONNECT CLOUDSQL ----------
cloud_sql_proxy is running.
Connections: ****:europe-west1:***-bdd.

---------- EXECUTE COMMAND ----------
/var/www/scripts-cloud/migrate.sh

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for /cloudsql/*** failed: Name or service not known (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = scorecard and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

here my code

```
  - name: "gcr.io/google-appengine/exec-wrapper"
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args:
      - -c
      - |
        /buildstep/execute.sh \
        -i europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/$$SERVICE_NAME/api \
        -e DB_CONNECTION=mysql \
        -e DB_SOCKET=$$DB_HOST \
        -e CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME=$$PROJECT_ID:$$PROJECT_REGION:$$PROJECT_INSTANCE \
        -e DB_DATABASE=$$DB_DATABASE \
        -e DB_USERNAME=$$DB_USERNAME \
        -e DB_PASSWORD=$$DB_PASSWORD \
        -e EMAIL_SUPER_ADMIN=$$EMAIL_SUPER_ADMIN \
        -e PWD_SUPER_ADMIN=$$PWD_SUPER_ADMIN \
        -s $$PROJECT_ID:$$PROJECT_REGION:$$PROJECT_INSTANCE \
        /var/www/scripts-cloud/migrate.sh
    secretEnv: ['DB_PASSWORD', 'DB_DATABASE', 'DB_USERNAME', 'DB_HOST', 'PROJECT_ID', 'PROJECT_REGION', 'PROJECT_INSTANCE', 'SERVICE_NAME', 'EMAIL_SUPER_ADMIN', 'PWD_SUPER_ADMIN']
```

If I launch a connection manually with a command cloud proxy

```
./cloud-sql-proxy --port 3307 ****:europe-west1:***-bdd
```

I can connect and use the bdd locally and launching everything I want

Did I forget something?

THanks

I reverify all the code, replace manually, launching locally

Comment: Ok i fail cause my .env doesn't contain DB_SOCKET value ;)

Comment: Please post your answer for the benefit of others.

Comment: I post it just on the first comment :) It was a variable DB_SOCKET which was missing :)

Answer (score 1):

Sharing this as a community wiki for the benefit of others

As mentioned by @shinzo94

> My .env doesn't contain DB_SOCKET value